# Iterating in jsp over Map<string,List<List<String>>>

Tags: jsp, json

I want to iterate over Map < String, List>>
in java:

```
final JSONObject mappedData = new JSONObject();
final Map<String, List<List<String>>> associatedUsecasesMap = new HashMap<String, List<List<String>>>();
//some code that populates map.
mappedData.put("usecaseDetailsMap",associatedUsecasesMap);
return mappedData;
```

In jsp
when I print with

```
<a:text>${usecases.get('usecaseDetailsMap').get('ARRIVED')}</a:text>
```

I get

```
[["ABC","Realm","patluria","test","1444209946120"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","Abhinav","1444719147503"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","Abhinav","1444719147503"],["ss","Realm","patluria","sa","1443590024585"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","eef","1444382236881"],["passport","Realm","patluria","testing","1444368146430"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","eef","1444382236881"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","as","1444210103588"],["saasa","Realm","patluria","as","1444372196955"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","sasd","1444727640485"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","eef","1444382223024"],["ss","Realm","patluria","sa","1443590006005"],["asa","Realm","patluria","asa","1444386667440"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","dadda","1444639933870"],["asa","Realm","patluria","asa","1444386667440"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","sasd","1444727626874"],["ss","Realm","patluria","sa","1444414479534"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","asa","1444729340806"],["ABC","Realm","patluria","as","1444209965115"],["ss","Realm","patluria","sa","1443590024585"],["saasa","Realm","patluria","as","1444372196955"]]
```

but I want to iterate on this so I am doing this

```
<c:forEach items="${usecases.get('usecaseDetailsMap')get('ARRIVED')}" var="usecase" >
```

But I get the following error: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

Can I know how to iterate over the List> based on a specified key.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over `Map` JSTL `forEach` uses it as `Map.Entry` instance.  Then you can use `entry.key` & `entry.value` in jsp. Therefore you can directly use Map in JSTL as follows:-

```
<c:forEach var="usecaseDetails" items="${usecaseDetailsMap}">
  ${usecaseDetails.key} ${usecaseDetails.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: what I want is not that. I want to fetch the List<List<String>> based on the key from map. then I need to iterate over it.

Comment: @Abhinav once you get the key and then check for equality you can then get its value using `c:if` and then iterate the values using `c:forEach` on value again.